# Change background-color on vertical scroll using jq

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to change the background-color of the menu bar on scroll, but for some reason the jq code I found doesn't work. The navbar is created using bootstrap.

```js
$(".navbar-top-fixed").jqScrollAnim({
    rep: {start: 0, end: 500},
    animation: {type:'color', property:'background-color', end:[255,255,255, 1]}
});
```

```css
.navbar-top-fixed{ 
  background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: is your jquery running after the document has loaded?

Comment: If you're asking me if other jq functions in the same jq document work, the answer is yes

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I'm asking, but this jquery line in particular is running after the `navbar-top-fixed` is rendered on the page so it can hook into it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a color animation script, try this one: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color